# UIWebView display RTF file with images & tables

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview, rtf

For a project I need to display the contents of a RTF file on an iPad. After some searches I found that you can load the RTF file in an UIWebView. However when I do this, the content of the file shows up, but its missing table borders, and images. Bold / Italic / Underlined text works fine.

The code I use to display the file:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"A" withExtension:@".rtf"];

NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);

NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[_webView loadRequest:req];
```

The RTF file:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4966217/A.rtf

How can I display the images and table borders in my app?

Comment: you should convert the source file to `HTML` format.

Comment: Have you got solution for this?

Comment: No never was able to fix it

Comment: Were you able to fix it? @geert

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to show rtf file then you can also use `QLPreviewController`.
It supports many file formats for preview.

Here is the documentation link for `QLPreviewController`:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

And here is sample code : 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010052

Comment: It does indeed show the RTF file, but it doesn't show table borders and images

Comment: My idea was, if your strictly need is not to show RTF in UIWebView then you can show it in QLPreviewController that shows the file as it is.

Comment: My problem was not the UIWebView, it was the content missing of the RTF file

Comment: As i have checked in QLPreviewController also, it is not showing table in RTF file. If possible then create HTML for your RTF content.

Comment: It isn't, since there is a database with about 15K RTF files in it

Answer (score -2):

Try this code

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForAuxiliaryExecutable:@"A.rtf"];
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
[_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

to convert it to html

http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development/loading-local-files-into-uiwebview/

http://kiefermat.com/2011/09/30/using-uiwebview-for-displaying-rich-text/

Comment: That does the same thing as it does now, it opens the file, and it shows the table without borders, and doesn't show the image.